# What type of hosting do I need? Informational site using Drupal, MYSQL, PHP, and more

Tags: web-hosting

A few friends and myself are working on a game for Android. I am looking to create a site that people can visit to be informed and updated about this game. It is mostly informational but in the future it could grow and I would possibly implement drupal and store login credentials in a DB.

What do I "need" in a hosting service from what I have described? They offer all sorts of security and stuff for $239437.33. I don't think I "need" these things.

In addition to what I need, who matches those needs?

Comment: You'll probably find better answers for this on webmasters.SE, shopping questions are typically considered off-topic for ServerFault.

Comment: You need to define your requirements and then sit down with various hosting providers to see what they have that meets your needs.  None of the Stack Exchange sites can do this for you, though we are happy to help if you have specific questions.

Comment: Try asking your favorite webhost; they usually have support people where you can tell them what you want (Drupal + MySQL + PHP) and they'll tell you the cheapest plan that can do it (which should be **very** cheap, those are low requirements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably start with shared hosting that offers PHP (version 5.2+) and MySQL.  If you can find one with a Drupal auto-installer, even better.  I assume the store will be a Drupal module, in which case you'll probably only need one database.

If you're in the UK, I'd recommend [Heart Internet](http://www.heartinternet.co.uk/web-hosting/) (the Home Pro package offers what you need, they have auto-installers too).

If the site starts getting busy, you can start thinking about a VPS, but shared hosting is much cheaper and easier and sufficient in many cases.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I've been asking around trying to find the appropriate place to ask. Sorry for being out of the context of serverfault. I'd vote up but I'm at -2 rep LOL :D

Answer (score -1):

I would actually recommend a VPS if you're willing to take on the technical requirements. A VPS gives you root access to a server of your choosing.

AWS and Linode are two great options(AWS is free for a micro). If you're not technically inclined enough to take on a server; look for a host that offers php/mysql(most do) and that should do you. I would shy away from a hosting provider that offers anything 'unlimited' though.